# Chrome webdrive bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)

Tags: docker, maven, jenkins, webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I have created a Dockerfile on my VM machine and used it to start a Jenkins instance as a Docker container. I also installed the Maven integration plugin in Jenkins. However, when I try to build my project, Chrome starts but it fails to bind, causing my test scenarios to not execute properly.

To summarize, I have set up Jenkins in a Docker container with Maven integration, but I'm facing issues with Chrome binding, which is preventing the successful execution of my test scenarios.

```
07:17:39 [1687763859.176][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
07:17:39 Starting ChromeDriver 113.0.5672.63 (0e1a4471d5ae5bf128b1bd8f4d627c8cbd55f70c-refs/branch-heads/5672@{#912}) on port 13947
07:17:39 Only local connections are allowed.
```